# Changing dependency in running spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to change dependency in already deployed application. So when application starts it send notification through email, but at some moment we should be able to change to send notification through sms.

How to do that in Spring Boot?

Comment: thats a work for a strategy pattern

Comment: @AmerQarabsa can you please give some links with examples how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

thats a work for a strategy pattern, it does not have anything to do with spring itself

You should have 2 strategies one for email and one for sms, in each strategy you will autowired the needed bean.

check this link for strategy implementation

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Comment: What do you think is the best approach to choosing the needed strategy *on runtime*? Is there a better option other than injecting the two strategies to the container and choosing the required one declaratively (by a simple if/switch statement)?

Comment: Strategy is used whenever we need to change behaviour in runtime while this behavior cannot be presented in hierarchialy way, you will need an interface for the strategies and the assignment of the used strategy should be done simply using conditions

Comment: What I don't like about it is that in most cases you have to inject both strategies while you only use one. I guess an option to resolve that is to get the needed bean explicitly.

Comment: if you will only use one there is no need for strategy, it will be a simple factory, strategy is used when there will be a change in the runtime, which means you will use more than one

Comment: You're right, and basically if we are referring to a singleton service that is handling different calls using different strategies, it makes sense that all the strategies will be injected to the service. Thanks!

Comment: @TomerA glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property in a Singleton bean? let's call it notificationMethod and assign by default EMAIL. (the property could be enum or string or int no matter).
You need a controller method to change the property.

```
@Autowired
private MyNotificationMethodHolderService service;
@RequestMapping(value = "/changeNotificationMethod")
@ResponseBody
public String change(@RequestParam("methodName") String methodName) {
    service.setNotificationMethod (methodName);
}
```

Your notification service checks the property and sends notification according to the value (Strategy pattern according to comments).

If you need to change method you invoke

```
<HOST>:<PORT>/context/changeNotificationMethod?methodName=SMS
```